# AWS Android Chat App

Tags: java, php, android, amazon-web-services

I am trying to make an android chat application. I am thinking about making it with aws. But the problem is that I am unable to find any good tutorial for doing this and I have no idea how to do it.

So could anyone please suggest some tutorial for sending push notification or on how to make a chat application?

Comment: *Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, **tutorial** or other off-site resource are off-topic* - **[what to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)**

Answer (score 1):

Firebase is well suited to this due to its "realtime database" feature. Here's a few tutorials I found by Googling

- https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-create-an-android-chat-app-using-firebase--cms-27397
- http://myapptemplates.com/simple-android-chat-app-tutorial-firebase-integration/
- https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-android/#0

Answer (score 1):

Check Socket.IO for android. ( https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client-java )

Its really easy to write a chat application. But you need a server side. 
Easy to write a simple server for this chat app.
Server reveice the all message from clients and broadcast the message, to all.

**Gradle:**

```
compile 'com.github.nkzawa:socket.io-client:0.5.1'
```

**Android manifest:**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

**Java**

```
public static Socket mSocket;
try {
            mSocket = IO.socket("http://192.168.1.104:4444");
            mSocket.connect();
        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

**Send messsage to server:**

```
MainActivity.mSocket.emit("message","Text here...");
```

**Create a listener for another message:**

```
MainActivity.mSocket.on("newMessage", onMessageArrive); // Oncreate


private Emitter.Listener onMessageArrive = new Emitter.Listener() {
        @Override
        public void call(final Object... args) {
            getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {

                    String data = (String)args[0];
                    // Here is all message. add it to list :) Or Push notif
                }
            });
        }
    };
```

// Server side:

```
var http = require('http');
var express = require('express'),
    app = module.exports.app = express();
var io = require('socket.io').listen(app.listen(4444));

io.on('connection', function (socket) {
  socket.on("message",function(msg){
      io.sockets.emit('newMessage', msg);
  });
});
```

Run:

```
npm install express
npm install socket.io
node filename.js
```

Just dont forget to check you IP! :)
Done! You have a Real Time Chat!!

Comment: I can use it but the problem is how to deploy them online.

Comment: Rent a server and run there your Node server. Than connect to the ip:port- I think a server is not expensive. Its about 3-5$ / month. It is good for developing.

Comment: Use Heroku, its free. You can deploy there!